# Unable to find script source

Tags: angularjs

I know asking this is silly but I am stuck and not getting out of it. I am new to Angular.js and have created the following program but it is not running as the program can't find the script sources..I have tried all the possible ways but haven't found the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{event.name}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the snapshot of my folder arrangement:

[image]

Comment: what is the error currently you are getting. share it to us ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but why are you using such an old version of AngularJs?

Comment: @Venkatraman: Never mind, got the solution.

Comment: @yeouuu: Actually I wanted to go with a stable version so have selected an older one, will go with 1.4.8 from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"> </script>
```

Should Be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
```

Depending on your location and path of `js` folder....

Comment: Good that my solution worked for you...and Thanks for marking as right answer....My pleasure... _/\_

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove the / before js in the src.if it is not working then check if it is the right path.