# Error: No module: NavSpot?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I have two basic files in my project and I'm trying to access the Angular controller in my HTML. I've tried many variations, including moving the scripts around, renaming the file, etc. If I place the core.js code inside a script directly in the HTML, it works. But once I place it in that separate file, I get the "No module: NavSpot" error. Any ideas?

dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="NavSpot">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="core.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <h1> {{ test }} </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

core.js

```
var app = angular.module('NavSpot', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "this is a test";
}]);
```

File structure:

```
NavSpot
- public
- - css
- - images
- - js
- - less
- - vendor
- views
- - dashboard.html
- - core.js
- app.js
- server.js
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right path to `core.js`?

Comment: Show your file structure

Comment: They are in the same folder, so I believe so.

Comment: I moved core.js inside my views so that it was in the same directory as dashboard.html just to be explicit. I posted my file structure in the main post.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, just the path, try different combinations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579775/unable-to-find-script-source Also add type to your script.

Comment: @SammyHowe i think you should try absolute patch

Comment: So if I launch JUST the HTML file, not my server or anything, it works. But once I try to do it via localhost:8080/dashboard, it does not work.